# Late 20th century graphic novel about following a time tourist

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

Here's something I have been looking for over 13 years. Somewhere between 1995-2000 I read this graphic novel-type of book my father had. It was in a big format (letter?), printed in colors - it was not too thick.

The plot was about a tourist from the distant future that travels through time and space to witness events and moments in time of great meaning. The time travel agency even mentioned safety precautions to not influence flow of time.

I read it back in Germany as a boy, but I'm sure it is not of German origin. The artwork was amazing and the pages consisted of full page illustrations with text boxes describing what we see.

I think it arced from ancient times, before life emerged, to the last moments of earth before the sun inflated and "ate" the planet. But I also remember that Niven's Ringworld was one of the places visited.

My memories are blurry at best but I'm still thinking about it. The artwork and prospects of distant future, where the last living thing on earth was a mindless blob of cells on a beach was really something else.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be *[Time Traveling Tourist](https://www.midtowncomics.com/product/1768766)*?

[image: Front cover of Time Traveling Tourist]

> Beethoven Jones travels time and space doing exactly what every tourist does, taking selfies.
> That changes when he meets Rebecca, and tastes the best donuts in history, however its never easy falling in love with a time traveler. Journeying from the prehistoric past, Tutankhamen's tomb, the wild west, Ancient Rome and beyond. A hilarious romantic comedy through the ages not to be missed.

Comment: Never mind... too recent. Leaving up here as a partial answer.

Comment: Appreciate the answer!